# Question about lambda calculus.

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

Hi so im really struggling right now with the lambda calculus. It doesnt make sense to me.

So i know that ($\lambda x \to x)(y)$ means i have a function which takes a number to itself. The confusing part hits in when i see something like

$(\lambda x \to gx)x$

Does this mean
i have a function which takes an x and outputs g and i should apply it to x?

or does it mean i have an a function which takes an x and outputs gx ?
My book says that {$g,x$} are free variables. What would that mean concretely. Im looking for intuition, nothing is making sense. :C

Comment: Can you tell us what book you are using, please. Does it really use $\to$ in its notation for $\lambda$-terms?

Comment: yes im using a script my university offers.its not really a book i can link if you want to see it.

Comment: Don't worry about the link, but does it really use the notation $\lambda x \to gy$? (When the rest of the world writes  $\lambda x.gy$ or $\lambda x \cdot g y$ or, when they're not thinking about $\lambda$-calculus, $x \mapsto gy$.)

Comment: yes it does use the notation with an arrow. Do you know any other sources you could recommend for the lambda calculus ?

Comment: Here's a list off the top of my head: the Wikipedia page isn't bad and will lead you too lots of other references. The book "The Lambda Calculus" by Barendregt is a very comprehensive reference (perhaps too comprehensive if you are new to the subject). Jesse Alama's [article in the Stanford Encyclopaeida of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/) is good as is Mike Gordon's book "Programming theory and its applications".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $(\lambda x\to x)$ is a function that takes a number (or, indeed, anything whether or not it is a number) to itself. When you say $(\lambda x\to x)y$ you're *applying* that function to $y$ (whatever $y$ is), and the result of that is just $y$.

In $(\lambda x\to gx)$ you have a function that takes something and returns the value of $g$ applied to that something -- as you describe it, a function that takes $x$ and produces $gx$.

However, again, when you write $(\lambda x\to gx)x$ you have taken the function just described and *applied it to $x$*, which would produce $gx$.

The statement that $g$ and $x$ are free variables means that the expression "$(\lambda x\to gx)x$" doesn't really have a value before you decide what the value of the variables $g$ and $x$ are going to be. It's a recipe for doing something with a thing you call $g$ and a thing you call $x$, but you can't really do it before you have decided what those things are going to be.

---

Note, by the way, that in $(\lambda x\to gx)x$ you have two *different* $x$ around. If we write it $(\lambda x_1\to gx_1)x_2$, the two ones shown as $x_1$ is just a dummy variable that tells you what the function does with its argument, whereas the $x_2$ is the *free variable* whose value you're supposed to decide.

Comment: Is the thing you did at the end an alpha conversion?, btw thank you a lot for helping me its a lot clearer now !

Comment: @asddf: Yes, exactly -- except that we're not supposed to $\alpha$-convert the free variable! But your $(\lambda x.gx)x$ is $\alpha$-equivalent to $(\lambda y.gy)x$. I was holding back on the fancy word in case you hadn't encountered it yet.

Comment: Just one last question: $\lambda x y \to t$ means that my function requires two variables ?

Comment: @asddf No.  For example $(\lambda xy \to t)r$ reduces to $(\lambda y \to t)$.  Another, $(\lambda xyz \to axbyczd)r$ reduces to $(\lambda yz \to arbyczd)$.  $\lambda xy \to t$ is just an abbreviation for $\lambda x \to (\lambda y \to t)$.

Comment: ok and $\lambda x \to (\lambda y \to t) $means we define a function that sends x to a function dfinition  which sends y to t ?

Comment: @asddf: Correct.

Comment: but why is this equivalent to $(\lambda xy \to t)$

Comment: @asddf: It is simply a _convention_ that this is what is meant when there are two or more letters after the $\lambda$. Formally only a single letter after the $\lambda$ is allowed; writing $\lambda x\to\lambda y\to t$ as $\lambda xy\to t$ is _nothing more_ than a convenient abbreviation for the former.

Comment: ok it makes sense now, thank you for taking your time to help me :))